# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host in aws

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have created an e-commerce site in angular js. And I need to host the same in amazon web service.

So inorder to host the same I created an ec2 instance first. Now after that added an rds instance with a security group of VPC by allowing all ip's as outbound and inbound. While creating security group I specified for mysql and for all connection.
Still after I remotely loged into the instance and try to connect to the end point from rds instance using

```
mysql -u username -p password -h ********.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

I get an error

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host xxxxxxxxx (0)
```

I created the instance from Asia Pacific (singapore) region since I am a resident of india.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It should be **`********.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`** instead of `********.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`

You do not need the port number in the  end.